# How do I only truncate a table in PSQL if only that table exist?

Tags: psql, sql-truncate

I want to replace drop & create with truncate.
So the first step i wand to add is check if the table already exists and truncate it.
How do I only truncate a table in PSQL if only that table exist?
I want something like `TRUNCATE TABLE IF EXISTS (table_name);`

`TRUNCATE TABLE IF EXISTS (table_name);`